# Frequency Adjusting with STM32 DAC

Tags: stm32, frequency, dac

I used STM32F407VG to create a 30 khz sine wave. Timer settings are; Prescaler = 2-1, ARR = 1, also the clock is 84 Mhz(the clock which runs DAC).

I wrote a function called generate_sin();

```
#define SINE_ARY_SIZE (360)
const int MAX_SINE_DEGERI = 4095; // max_sine_value
const double BASLANGIC_NOKTASI = 2047.5; //starting point
uint32_t sine_ary[SINE_ARY_SIZE];
void generate_sine(){
    for (int i = 0; i < SINE_ARY_SIZE; i++){
        double deger = (sin(i*M_PI*360/180/SINE_ARY_SIZE) * BASLANGIC_NOKTASI) + BASLANGIC_NOKTASI; //double value
        sine_ary[i] = (uint32_t)deger; // value
}
```

This is the function which creates sine wave. I used HAL DMA to send DAC output variables.

```
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
generate_sine();
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, sine_ary, SINE_ARY_SIZE, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
```

These are the codes i used to do what i want. But im having a trouble to change frequency without changing prescaler or ARR.

So here is my question. Can i change frequency without changing timer settings ? For example i want to use buttons and whenever i push button i want my frequency to change.

Comment: Is it working okay except changing the frequency? BTW, I can't see frequency settings in your code.

Comment: @Tagli Yes it is working really well. I change the frequency with changing SINE_ARY_SIZE which is my sampling rate. Other settings are constant.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid changing TIM frequency? Changing TIM frequency is much better then recalculating a sine look-up table.

Comment: @Bowman I am ready to provide a solution for the question you just removed.:)

Answer (score -1):

The generate_sine function will give you one period of a sine wave which has SINE_ARY_SIZE of samples.

To increase the frequency you need to make the period shorter (for 2x frequency, you would have half the number of samples per period). So you should calculate the array for smaller SINE_ARY_SIZE (which will fill just part of the original buffer with a shorter sine wave) and also put this smaller value in the HAL_DAC_Start_DMA function.

Decreasing the frequency will require making the array longer.

You should declare the sine_ary with a maximum length that you will need (for lowest frequency). Make sure it fits in RAM.

```
#define MAXIMUM_ARRAY_LENGTH 360

uint32_t usedArrayLength = 180;

const double amplitude = 2047.5;

uint32_t sine_ary[MAXIMUM_ARRAY_LENGTH];

void generate_sine(){
    for (int i = 0; i < usedArrayLength; i++){
        double value = (sin(i*M_PI*2/usedArrayLength) * amplitude) + amplitude;
        sine_ary[i] = (uint32_t)value; // value
}
```

This will have two times higher frequency than the original code, because it only has 180 samples per period, compared to 360.

Start it using

```
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, sine_ary, usedArrayLength, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
```

To change the frequency, stop DAC, change the value of usedArrayLength (smaller value means higher frequency, must be less or equal to MAXIMUM_ARRAY_LENGTH). Then call the generate_sine function and start the DAC again by the same function (that now uses new usedArrayLength).

Frequency will be: Clock/prescaler/ARR/usedArrayLength

Also, you should use uint16_t for the array (values are from 0 to 4095, the DAC is 12bit I suppose) and DMA should be set to Half-word (2 bytes per value).

Comment: `To change the frequency, stop DAC ....` extremely naive and bad way. In most cases, you can't stop generation and you need to avoid jitter or signal distortion.

Comment: @Jiří Maier Thank you for your effort. So can i do this with a button ? I mean i can create a variable which called buttonState and when the buttonState goes 1 other settings should be applied to change frequency. Do you think is it possible to do that ?

Comment: @0___________ Yes in my case i should not stop generation. Whenever the button was pushed frequency should be changed without stopping generation. Jiri thank you for your time btw. I will think on that and will try to think a solution.

Comment: @Kırambor, Why don't you want to change the timer setting rather than changing the frequency by recalculating samples? Calculating samples once and then changing the frequency of the timer seems simpler than recalculating the array each time you change frequency.

Comment: Because i dont know how to apply new timer settings. I mean timer settings are in a function for example called void TimerSettings();. When i push the button i will change prescaler from 2 to 4. But is it possible to do that with a button state ?

Comment: You can change timer's period using __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTOREALOAD(&htim2, newValue); or __HAL_TIM_SET_PRESCALER for prescaler. (those functions are just a macro for setting ARR or PSC)

Comment: To change frequency using pushbutton, just check the input (either poll it in while loop or using interrupt) and set new frequency whenever button state changes.

Comment: @JiříMaier Thanks a lot for your help. I will try it.